# using polymer with jsp

Tags: jsp, polymer

I use polymer with jsp.
I installed polymer and some components (iron-icons, paper-icon-button..) into WebContent folder. (WebContent/bower_components/iron-xxx..or paper-xxx..)
main.jsp located in WebContent folder too.
But main.jsp appeared nothing.

[main.jsp]

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html" >

  </head>
  <body>
     <paper-icon-button icon="menu" style="color: red;"></paper-icon-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is wrong...
I think something was wrong polymer elements ..
What should I do?.... uuu

Comment: What browser? If Chrome, press `Ctrl+Shift+I` to open the Developer Console and check the Sources tab to ensure the `iron-icons.html` page was loaded. If it was not, your import's file path may be incorrect.

Comment: I use chrome. and I check the sources tab but iron-icons.html page was loaded...I don't know what is wrong....

Comment: Your import file path is incorrect. Double-check it against the location of the files on the server and the server's settings.

Comment: Shouldn't you also have to import the `paper-icon-button` component?

Comment: .................Thank you... ;;;; I solve it... I forgot to import the paper-icon-button.....OTL....